# 3D vector drawing software

Tags: vector-graphics, 3d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Draw 3D vectors](https://superuser.com/questions/394327/draw-3d-vectors)

I need a program to make a 3D drawing easy and carefully at a half of a day. 3D drawing consists of:

1. vectors,
2. lines,
3. arcs for angle  between two vectors or lines vector,
4. vector, line, arc labels.

Label requirements:

1. Greek symbols (phi, alpha, theta, ...)
2. showing a fraction ability (phi/2)
3. font style such as italic, bold, ...

I need to insert this drawing in my paper, but it will be great if an editor allow to watch the image in 3D.

Comment: **You've already asked a very similar question**. Please [edit it](http://superuser.com/posts/394327/edit) to include any missing details, as it seems your older question didn't receive too much attention.